# kafka server: Offset's topic has not yet been created

Tags: go, apache-kafka, sarama

I'm using Kafka server 0.9 + zookeper. I'm new with Kafka. It's running in virtualbox , I can connect to it using public IP so it's working ... more or less: can get topics and messages.
So for now I have 2 issues:

1. I can't find anything at __consumer_offsets (empty) and that's why I've got issue with the go simple consumer script throwing error: `kafka server: Offset's topic has not yet been created`; when i check at zookeeper-shell.sh console by command `ls /brokers/topics/__consumer_offsets` it errors me : `Node does not exist: /brokers/topics/__consumer_offsets`
2. (maybe they are connected) I've got minor warning when autocreating topic: `WARN  NetworkClient - Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 4157 : {topicName=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE}`

Any help it highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason was successfully found in logs : `Number of alive brokers '1' does not meet the required replication factor '3' for the offsets topic` 
you need to post into your `server.properties` file following option : `offsets.topic.replication.factor=1`. This option will not let you do anything till the count reaches 3 but since you have it set as a playbox - you usually have 1 only.

Answer (score 1):

The `__consumer_offsets` topic is created automatically when a consumer using a group connects to the cluster.

By default, Sarama does not support groups (https://github.com/Shopify/sarama/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-can-i-use-sarama-to-monitor-or-join-a-consumer-group), so unless you are using the cluster extension (https://github.com/bsm/sarama-cluster) this is expected.

You can use the `kafka-console-consumer.sh` tool that comes with Kafka to create it if you want.